# Liferay search static facet for exluding a tag

Tags: search, filter, liferay

I would like to add a static facet to my Liferay search portlet in order to filter out contents having a specific tag, i.e. I do not want to display the assets which are assigned this tag to. I tried several options, but had no success so far. Even I was not able to create a facet for displaying assets having a specific tag. I have another non-static facet for tags, could it be a problem?

This is my last try:

```
{
    "displayStyle": "asset_entries",
    "weight": 1.0,
    "static": true,
    "order": "OrderHitsDesc",
    "data": {
        "values": ["my-tag"],
        "frequencyThreshold": 0
    },
    "label": "label",
    "className": "com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.facet.AssetEntriesFacet",
    "fieldName": "assetTagNames"
},
```

But I also tried `displayStyle: asset_tags` and `MultiValueFacet` as `className`.
Any ideas, how to configure this facet?

Comment: Menawhile I found this page: https://jira.portletfaces.org/browse/LPS-28378 It says that it is not possible to create both a dynamic and static facet for the same field. Removing the dynamic facet, the static one worked. Just for curiousity, any suggestion for using "NOT" in the values field? Is it possible?